# How to get the parent page inside a frame?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, frame

I got a page, in which there's a frame (that contains 2 input forms, that can be switched to with 2 buttons above the form) and a listView which contains the inputs from the user. When the User finishes the input, I want to pass an Object from the frame to the parent page.

I tried getting the Parent with the `Parent` property, but the parent property is for some reason `null`. I also tried to search for a solution on the web, but I wasn't able to find anything helpful. Does anyone of you know my problem can be solved?

Parent Page:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Form1"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="Form2"/>

            <Frame x:Name="inputFrame" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Black"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Frame Inside the Parent Page:

```
<Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Padding="10" Background="AliceBlue" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="DarkSlateGray" KeyUp="textInput">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Content="Beschreibung:" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="inputDesc" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Width="150" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

        <Label Content="Zeit:" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,10,10"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="inputHours" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,10,0,10" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label Content=":" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,10,5,10"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="inputMins" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,10,0,10" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

        <Button x:Name="addBtn" IsEnabled="False" Content="Hinzufügen" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="0, 10, 0, 10" Click="addBtnClick"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="info" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="0,10,0,0" MaxWidth="150" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" TextAlignment="Center" Height="40"/>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding items}" Name="listView" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="9" SelectionChanged="itemSelected" Background="WhiteSmoke">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Desc}" Header="Beschreibung"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Time}" Header="Zeit"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}" Header="Datum"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out how this can be solved:

You just give a reference of the parent page to the page in the frame through the constructor, like this:

```
    private void changeToForm1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        inputFrame.Content = new Form1(this);
    }
```

Now, you can just save the reference into a variable and call methods to transfer the data to the parent page.